# How can I order hierarchy trees by branch in a select statement returning all hierarchy levels?

Tags: sql, select, oracle11g

This is my current SQL:

```
SELECT filter_id, parent_id, level_id, match 
FROM t_filters
ORDER BY level_id;
```

It shows the following:

```
ID      PARENT  RANK    FILTER VALUE
10004           1       HQ
10002           1       Finance
10006           1       IT
10003   10006   2       HQ - Central
10005   10004   2       HQ - Non Core & Legacy
10001   10005   3       Non Core
```

My first attempt here orders the records by the hierarchy_level_id, which is basically the rank.

Note the parent field is null where the record is at the top of the hierarchy.

Also, the branch can have any length from 1 to 8 entries (8 is the current max but could theoretically increase by 1 or 2).

What I want to show is the following, which should use the parent field to collate the individual branches of the hierarchy together:

```
ID      PARENT  RANK    FILTER VALUE
10004           1       HQ
10005   10004   2       HQ - Non Core & Legacy
10001   10005   3       Non Core
10002           1       Finance
10006           1       IT
10003   10006   2       HQ - Central
```

Comment: Why is the order among top-of-the-hierarchy elements `10004`, `10002`, `10006`?

Comment: @LukasEder No reason - the order of the branches in my example is chance, but thinking about it, I would order them alphabetically by filter value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution orders siblings by `id`. In your comments, you've mentioned wanting to order siblings by (filter) `value`. Just replace the relevant expression to achieve this.

Use recursive SQL, Oracle syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM t_filters
START WITH parent IS NULL
CONNECT BY parent = PRIOR id
ORDER SIBLINGS BY id
```

Alternatively, SQL standard syntax (the standard and some databases would require a `RECURSIVE` keyword, but Oracle doesn't allow it). A bit more tedious, but more extensible:

```
WITH /* RECURSIVE */ r (id, parent, rank, value, path) AS (
  SELECT id, parent, rank, value, '' || id
  FROM t_filters
  WHERE parent IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT f.id, f.parent, f.rank, f.value, r.path || '/' || f.id
  FROM r
  JOIN t_filters f ON r.id = f.parent
)
SELECT *
FROM r
ORDER BY path
```

Comment: Nitpicking: "SQL standard syntax" would _require_ the use of the `recursive` in front of the CTE name: `with recursive cte (...) as (...) ` - but Oracle does not comply with the standard here.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You're absolutely right, although, I must say, I don't mind Oracle's deviation in this context.

Comment: @LukasEder great answer, thanks, although I have problems with the standard SQL when setting the order of my branches after the recursive ordering on the parent. I have named the `path` column in both `selects` in the `union`. Didn't manage to solve that.

Comment: @Adam: I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. But if you ask a new question, I'll be very happy to help